# Insert data array in SQL after searching from another SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, insert

I have an array `$members` that contains some `ID`(maximum 6 in number) from the table `users`. Using the following code, I loop through each index of `$members`, search for the details and store them in another array.

```
        foreach($members as $key=>$value){
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,email FROM users WHERE id='$value'");
            if ($res === false) {
                echo mysql_error();
                die;
            }
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

            if($row['id'])
            {
                $members_name[]=$row['name'];//array for name
            }
        }
```

Now I want to insert the `ID` & `names` that are stored in the array into another TABLE `register` in the following format:
(The left side are the `rows` in my TABLE `register`)

```
mem_0_id-->$members[0]
mem_0_name-->$members_name[0]
mem_1_id-->$members[1]
mem_1_name-->$members_name[1]
mem_2_id-->$members[2]
mem_2_name-->$members_name[2]
mem_3_id-->$members[3]
mem_3_name-->$members_name[3]
mem_4_id-->$members[4]
mem_4_name-->$members_name[4]
```

How can I insert in this way? using just a single INSERT statement?

Answer (score 0):

haven't tried this, but here is my answer anyway :)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO register(id, name) VALUES ($members[0], $members_name[0])";

for($i=1; $i<count($members); $i++)
{
    $query .= ", ($members[$i], $members_name[$i])";
}
```

then try to execute the query..

Answer (score 0):

Do you do anything else with the array, or are you just retrieving it from one table in order to insert it into another?

If so then you can do the whole thing like this.

```
$memberIds = implode(',', $members); // comma separated list of member ids
$query = "insert into register (id, name) select id, name from users where id in ($memberIds)";
mysql_query($query); // this will select and insert in one go
```

If you do need to keep the array in memory, then it's still a good idea to get it all out at once

```
$memberIds = implode(',', $members); // comma separated list of member ids
$query = "select id, name from users where id in ($memberIds)";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $memberData[] = $row;
}
```

That's because running a query inside a loop is very bad for performance. Every time you run a query there is an overhead, so getting all the data at once means you pay this overhead once rather than multiple times.

Then you can build a statement to insert multiple rows:

```
$sql = "insert into register (id, name) values ";
$sql .= "(" . $memberData[0]['id'] . "," . $memberData[0]['name'] . ")";
for($i = 1; $i < count($memberData); $i++) {
    $sql .= ",(" . $memberData[$i]['id'] . ",'" . $memberData[$i]['name'] . "')";
}
mysql_query($sql);
```

It's a bit nasty because of the commas and quotes but if I've done it correctly then if you do

```
echo $sql;
```

you should get something like

```
insert into register (id, name) values (1, 'john'), (2, 'jane'), (3, 'alice');
```

You can see that the first way, where you select and insert in one statment, is a lot nicer and easier so if you don't do anything else with the array then I highly recommend doing it that way.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer completely. How will your code ensure that details are getting inserted in `mem_1_id`, `mem_1_name`..and so on?

Comment: And, I'm not doing anything with the array. There's a php form that takes in `ID`s in an array-->pass it into another php-->search for the respective names-->and store them in another table.

Comment: well, if you use the first code (select and insert in one go) then it just takes the ids and names from one table and puts them in the other. Isn't that what you wanted, maybe I misunderstood? (I've also edited my answer so that you can chose the other way where you fetch the array and then separately insert it ... but I think the first code should suit you fine given your comments).